# How to express "Not this character including boundary" in a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

The regex below matches all sequences closely surrounded by single asterisk characters, which is how italic text is emphasized in Markdown. I want to format the text *including the asterisks used for emphasizing*. In addition to that I do allow free standing asterisks inside the sequence. Example `*This is italic text\n with * in between*`.

```
/\*[^\*\s]([^\*]|(\*\s))*[^\*\s]\*/g
```

Moreover, in Markdown, bold text is emphasized very similar, by double asterisk characters. To match those, I use this regex:

```
/\*\*[^\*\s]([^\*]|(\*\s))*[^\*\s]\*\*/g
```

Both work for their own, but when being applied together, the inner part of bold text is also detected as italic text. So except of the outer asterisks, the formatted text is both bold and italic. To fix that, I would have to express italic sequences aren't allowed to be wrapped by a second pair of asterisks.

The issue is that `[^\*]` requires any other character, thus requires a character at all. How can I express that the first regex above doesn't match if their are additional asterisks wrapped around, while still matching at the very start or end of the search string?

As a note, I use JavaScript so there is no look behind available.

Comment: Markdown shouldn't really be parsed with regexps, but with proper parser instead. Speaking of that, there's lots of hits for markdown javascript parser" on net.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov Good point, I should have pointed that out myself. Even though I'm aware of that fact, in my case it actually makes sense to use regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit**: since I had misunderstood the question, I propose to you a new pattern with your constraints:

```
/\*((?:[^\s*]+|\s+\*?)*)?\*/
```

The interest is that the whole pattern contains the markers and the capturing group the content inside. Note that the content is optional (`"**"` are valid markers around an empty content)

**old post**:

What you ask is impossible because there is no rule to choose which asterisk in the string is the closing asterisk. If you want to use the asterisk as a marker you must require the user to escape literal asterisks.

Example string:

```
*This is italic text\n with \* in between* text *an other italic part* text
```

To deal with this kind of strings, you can use this pattern to avoid escaped characters:

```
/\*(?:[^*\\]+|\\{2}|\\[\s\S])*\*/
```

Comment: The first asterisk following closely without whitespace is the closing asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

You can say "no characters, or a non-* character":

```
(^|[^\*])
```

and most probably, the escape within a character class is redundant:

```
(^|[^*])
```

same applies to the end marker:

```
($|[^*])
```